# How to generate a Concept tree from set of keywords

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, keyword

I am looking for an approach in NLP , where i can generate a concept tree from a set of keywords.

**Here is the scenario**, i have extracted a set of keywords from a research paper. Now i want to arrange these keywords in form of a tree where most general keyword comes on top. At next level of tree  will have keywords that are important to understand upper level concept and will be more specific as compared to upper level keywords. And the same way tree will grow.

**Something like this** :[image]

I know there are many resources that can help me to solve this problem. Like **[Wikipedia dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download)**, [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/). But i do not know how to proceed with them.

My preferred programming language is Python. Do you know any python library or package which generate this?
I am also very interested to see the use of Machine learning approach to solve this problem.
I will really appreciate your any kind of help.

Comment: If you want t o down vote this question, then at least, leave a comment explaining , what's wrong with this question.

Answer (score 1):

One way of looking at the problem is, given a set of documents, identify topics from them and also the dependencies between the topics.

So, for example, if you have some research papers as input (large set of documents), the output would be what topics the papers are on and how those topics are related in a hierarchy/tree. One research area that tries to tackle this is Hierarchical topic modeling and you can read more about this [here](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2466-hierarchical-topic-models-and-the-nested-chinese-restaurant-process.pdf) and [here](http://www.cse.ust.hk/%7Elzhang/teach/6931a/slides/3.HTM.pdf).

But if you are just looking at creating a tree out of a bunch of keywords (that are somehow obtained) and no other information is available, then it needs knowledge of real world relationships and can perhaps be a rule-based system where we define Math --> Algebra and so on.

There is no way for a system to understand that algebra comes under math other than by looking at large no. of documents and inferring that relationship (see first suggestion) or if we manually map that relationship (perhaps, a rule-based system). That is how even humans learn those relationships.